# Access Azure ADLS Gen 2 from Hadoop On-Prem using CLI

Tags: azure, apache-spark, hadoop, azure-data-lake-gen2

I basically want to list files under an ADLS Gen 2 Container using `hadoop fs -ls` from a standalone on-prem Cloudera Cluster. However I am getting this error:

Command ran from bash:

```
hadoop fs -Dfs.azure.account.key.accountName.dfs.core.windows.net="accessKey" -Dfs.azure.createRemoteFileSystemDuringInitialization=true -ls abfss://containerName@accountName.dfs.core.windows.net/
```

Error:

```
WARN fs.FileSystem: Failed to initialize fileystem abfss://containerName@accountName.dfs.core.windows.net/:Invalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.key ls: Invalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.key
```

Then, I ran this same `fs -ls` command from within a spark program by configuring:

```
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.azure.account.auth.type.accountName.dfs.core.windows.net','SharedKey')
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.azure.account.key.accountName.core.windows.net','accessKey')
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.abfss.impl','org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.SecureAzureBlobFileSystem')
```

The error from Spark Shell:

```
WARN fs.FileSystem: Failed to initialize fileystem abfss://containerName@accountName.dfs.core.windows.net/: Configuration property accountName.dfs.core.windows.net not found
```

Note:

- PySpark read and write to this ADLSGen2 container is working as expected after setting up the spark conf(). The issue is only when I try this with -fs commands as I eventually want to be using distcpy() as well, along with PySpark.
- I haven't configured anything on core-site.xml. Rather, I want to pass all keys, parameters and any settings independently within the program or script's context, even on bash. Looking for a solution that meets this criteria.
- Also, not using oAuth for this, since I am just running a POC. For now, I am only interested in checking this out using SharedKey for testing.

Can someone help me identify the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

As per the **[article](https://docs.cloudera.com/cdp-private-cloud-base/7.1.3/managing-clusters/topics/cm-adls-access.html),** please **note** the following limitations:

***ADLS*** is not supported as the default filesystem. Do not set the ***default file system*** property (fs. default fs) to an **abfss://** URI. You can use ***ADLS*** as ***a secondary*** filesystem while ***HDFS*** remains the ***primary*** filesystem.

Please follow the **reference** it has detailed information about:

- Access Azure ADLS Gen 2 from Hadoop On-Prem using CLI
- Configured on core-site.xml
- You can pass keys and parameters.

**Reference:**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h3jYrhl4Y4M

https://docs.cloudera.com/runtime/7.2.10/cloud-data-access/topics/cr-cda-hadoop-file-system-commands.html